# Why do three of four of these gesture recognizers work? (Down doesn't work)

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

This is my class.  For some reason, up, left and right work just fine.  Down doesn't ever seem to get recognized.

The first part is part of viewDidLoad.  I included the whole function "responseToSwipeGesture"

```
// Part of viewDidLoad
        // Setup gesture recognizers
        var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        var swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

        var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        var swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
        swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
```

// End of viewDidLoad section

```
func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
            println("Swiped right")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down:
            println("Swiped down")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up:
            println("Swiped up")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
            println("Swiped left")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Typo in your code

```
var swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
```

`swipeDown` instead of `swipeUp`.